blazor web app .net8 - negociate auth - http 403 when refresh page
I have a problem with windows authentication and blazor web app .net8, everything works fine except for one detail:
When I'm on a route with an authorization attribute, if I press F5 on this page, I get an http 403.
In order to reproduce my problem, I started from a blank blazor web app project. Here are the steps I followed:

Add the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate package
Wrap the  in a  in Routes.razor
Change the  to an  in Routes.razor
Add to Program.cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate(); builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy);

I then created a simple permission to reproduce the problem:
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("view", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Permission", "view"));
});

I created a CustomAuthenticationStateProvider to systematically add this authorization
and added the following attribute to the Counter example page:
@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "view")]

When I navigate to this page via the menu, I access the page correctly and everything is fine.
If I press F5, I get an http 403 error. Could someone please explain what's wrong?
Thanks in advance
Edit 1 :
it's a really basic CustomAuthenticationStateProvider class for my test :
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    public IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor { get; set; }

    public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(IConfiguration conf, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        if (HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "username")
            }, "windows auth");

            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Permission", "view"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "username"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "username"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "username"));
            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            return new AuthenticationState(user);
        }
        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal());
    }
}


Could you share the CustomAuthenticationStateProvider code?

i wrote a Edit1

@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "view")] won't work here. It works before the CustomAuthenticationStateProvider. So the "permission" claim is not added when pass the authorize pipeline. You could use AuthorizeView instead. It will work after the CustomAuthenticationStateProvider. Try modify the Counter page like following:
@page "/counter"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

//apply view policy
<AuthorizeView Policy="view">
   //only display when pass
    <Authorized>
        <h1>Counter</h1>

        <p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        @{
            //if not authorize redirect to somewhere
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"https://www.google.com");
        }
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>


I was also having such an annoying problem involving Reload and Blazor .NET8.
It seems that, when you first go to a page, an auth is made to the API / Controllers (Server Side).But, when you reload it, it seems to try an auth with the page (Client Side), that return as error.
I saw an solution some days ago using an AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler in Server Side, that resolved the Reload problem, but, it removed the need of authentication in the API because it just passed any call to the next middleware, not caring for the auth. I managed to solve it adding some code to the same Middleware, hope it helps you:
First, create the class
public class AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler : IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler {
    public async Task HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
    {
        if (authorizeResult.Succeeded || !context.GetEndpoint().DisplayName.Contains("Controller"))
            await next(context);
        else if (authorizeResult.Forbidden)
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
        else
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
    } }

You have to use the following libs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy;

Then, inject it in Server`s Program.cs (just before Build)
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler, AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler>();

Now, my app is working fine with the reload and the authentication.
